# Why escaping closures require us to refer to self explicitly?

Tags: swift

Apple's Swift documentation says that:

> Marking a closure with @escaping means you have to refer to self
>   explicitly within the closure.

```
var completionHandlers: [() -> Void] = []

func someFunctionWithEscapingClosure(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandlers.append(completionHandler)
}

func someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    closure()
}

class SomeClass {
    var x = 10
    func doSomething() {
        someFunctionWithEscapingClosure { self.x = 100 }
        someFunctionWithNonescapingClosure { x = 200 }
    }
}
```

But I am not able to understand the reason behind this?

In one of his Stanford Lectures (I don't exactly remember which one), Paul Hegarty said that Swift indicates the possibility of retention cycle by forcing you to write self. So is there a possibility of retention cycle while using escaping closures? Or is there any other reason why we have to explicitly refer to self within the closures marked as escaping?

And why in the other case (non escaping closures), there is no possibility of retention cycle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://buildingvts.com/escaping-non-escaping-closures-memory-management-and-you-cb936c60a9d1), it describes the differences.

Answer (score 2):

Self is used to keep/capture the instance of the object you want to send the message. If you don’t use self, then the compiler wouldn’t know where to send the message

The stanford lecture is right, but why does this happen? Having self in a closure can turn into a reference cycle where the object is never let go. You can avoid this by using weak self or unknown self. You should only use weak self or unknown self however to avoid a strong reference cycle.

Let me know if that answers your question properly or if you need anymore help

Comment: Thanks, for your efforts. But I already know these things. My question is specifically related to the difference in behavior of escaping and non-escaping closures.
Why we are required to use self.x in escaping closure and not in non-escaping closure.
Thanks again. :)